# Difference between [y][x] and [y, x] when reading a pixel on an image in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Is there any difference for reading values of a pixel on an image with `img[y][x]` and `img[y, x]` in Python using OpenCV?

I'm a beginner to image processing, and to me, the former one is easier to loop (understandably). I wonder if it would be better to continue using it in future or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing) state:

> So note that x[0,2] = x[0][2] though the second case is more
> inefficient as a new temporary array is created after the first index
> that is subsequently indexed by 2.

In short: `img[y, x]` should be preferred over `img[y][x]`